# How to change OpenVPN server address?

Tags: openvpn

Currently my openvpn server has ip address 10.8.0.1. I want to change it to 10.9.0.1. I tried changing the following lines in server.conf

```
# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

But when I restart OpenVPN it is still getting the address 10.8.0.1. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: This quoestion has been answered here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/586703/how-do-i-assign-specific-ip-address-to-my-openvpn-server/813986#813986

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it all right. Make sure that this address is not overridden later in the configuration file.

You should restart openVPN by executing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

Restarting `server.conf` only is possible with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart server
```

Comment: When you say "*not overridden later in the configuration file*", are there any scenarios where you have several `server a.b.c.d x.x.x.x` lines (except for copy-paste errors)?

Comment: @Matthieu Copy-paste errors are most likely to result in duplicates. I guess (but am not sure) that the cmdline is another way to override: `openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --server a.b.c.d x.x.x.x` (when you use the init script, this should not happen, but when using NetworkManager or sth, it is worth checking out)